# what is dart equivalence function for a filtering a list?

Tags: list, flutter, dart, filtering

what is dart equivalence function of filtering a list? The following java code contains boolean value argument to performs filtering on a list. how best can this be represented in dart?

```
public List<playlist> findVideos(Predicate<Playlist> filter) {
        return videos.stream().filter(filter).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Dart has [`where`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Iterable/where.html) method for `Iterable` class.

For example:

```
  final list = <int>[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
  print(list.where((i) => i > 4)); // prints [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Comment: Note that `.where()` returns an `Iterable`, so if you want a `List`, you'll need to call `.toList()` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Dart's [collection-for and collection-if](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#collection-operators) constructs allows you to build lists directly with expressions very similar to control flow statements.  For example:

```dart
List<playlist> findVideos(bool Function(Playlist) filter) {
  var filteredList = [
    for (var playlist in videos.stream())
      if (filter(playlist))
        playlist,
  ];

  // ...
}
```